# Editor infers param type correctly but still complains that param is 'any' type

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

As the title says, the type is inferred correctly (see below image) but I still get a TS error complaining about `any` type. Full code is below the image.

Is this an editor or TypeScript issue? Perhaps something else I haven't considered? Thanks.

[image: editor inferred type]

```js
export function createArrayCycle<T>(array: T[]): <U>(func?: (arg: T) => U) => T {
  let cycleCount = 0;

  return function cycle<U>(func): T | U {
    if (cycleCount === array.length) {
      cycleCount = 0;
    }

    if (func) {
      return func(array[cycleCount++]);
    }

    return array[cycleCount++];
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the compiler error; you must have `"noImplicitAny"` enabled in your `tsconfig.json` (or have `"strict"` set to `true`). If the compiler can't infer the parameter type from usage, it falls back to `any` type; with `"noImplicitAny"` enabled, it reports an error whenever it would have inferred `any`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny.

You need to either disable this option to make the compiler tolerate parameters without declaring their type or specify the parameter type explicitly